# Is it possible and if so, is there a performance benefit in combining Minimal API and classic controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have a dozen of controllers that don't take too much of a load and there are 2 particular endpoints that get higher load.

I am wondering:

1. Is it possible to combine minimal api with regular api endpoints?
2. Are there performance benefits in that particular case when requests land on those 2 endpoints implemented with minimal api?

I've seen some videos by Nick Chapsas doing tests comparing classic vs minimal api and there was a difference of ~15% just by switching to minimal api.

if thats possible by combining the two, i'd definitely go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to combine minimal api with regular api endpoints?

Yes

> Are there performance benefits in that particular case when requests land on those 2 endpoints implemented with minimal api?

Yes.